# React Native Expo "AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading" error

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a React Native project with Expo, I installed Expo client on my Android phone. It used to work well so far. But even though I didn't change any code, I now get the following error when I scan the QR code from my phone. This error is shown on terminal and phone screen keeps blank.

```
AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:
value@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:1051:3370
value@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:1051:12254
renderCard@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:1051:2218
map@[native code]
value@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:1051:5886
jr@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:92:48721
na@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:92:72881
ra@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:92:73371
Oa@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:92:80972
Wa@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:92:80310
Aa@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:92:79323
sa@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:92:78013
xr@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:92:42191
xr@[native code]
w@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:993:931
onFinish@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:993:476
/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:581:1090
p@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:151:423
/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:151:1740
p@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:151:423
n@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:151:898
/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:151:1047
f@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:114:155
/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:114:882
y@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:119:657
C@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:119:1021
callImmediates@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:119:3216
callImmediates@[native code]
value@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:31:2873
/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:31:1264
value@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:31:2565
value@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/33.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40sulun%2Fnoyz-alpha1753997165-33.0.0:31:1234
value@[native code]
value@[native code]
```

It works seamlessly on another phone. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It again works well after resetting the Expo client on my phone. So,

- Go to Settings -> Installed apps -> Expo
- Clear all data

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by closing and reloading the Expo app on my phone.

Comment: Prefer posting this as a comment