# Expo - AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading

Tags: react-native, expo

My ejected expo app has been working for a long time. However, i recently had this error when trying to run it. I have already tried clearing the data for the expo app, that does not seem to help. Currently, I am on expo 32. I tried updating to expo 35, but ran into too many errors to continue

```
AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:
value@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:976:858
or@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:90:43867
Or@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:90:57792
jr@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:90:58238
vi@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:90:63439
yi@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:90:62987
Hr@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:90:61339
enqueueSetState@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:90:31618
setState@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:59:2084
onFinish@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:910:9944
/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:903:1090
p@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:141:423
/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:141:1740
p@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:141:423
n@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:141:898
/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:141:1047
f@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:107:155
/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:107:882
y@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:110:657
C@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:110:1021
callImmediates@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:110:3216
callImmediates@[native code]
value@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:28:2902
/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:28:1274
value@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:28:2594
value@/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/32.0.0/cached-bundle-experience-%40devname%2Fproject-name-1636950914-32.0.0:28:1244
value@[native code]
value@[native code]
```

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585831/react-native-expo-apploading-threw-an-unexpected-error-when-loading-error

Comment: i said that I tried that, but it didnt work for me

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue or it is randomly happens?

Comment: Can you share your code with the package.json and Apploding part?

Comment: @AbhishekPatel did you manage to find a fix?

Comment: @Norfeldt I believe upgrading expo versions fixed this